# Is it stylistically correct to use "me" after an adjective ? Like "Intelligent me"

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, writing-style

I am a non-native speaker and I was just wondering whether it is stylistically and grammatically correct to write something like 
"smart me made the same mistake again"
or
"Intelligent me could not solve the riddle" 
is this similar to saying "fifteen-year-old me?"
Can I say "my smart self" instead ?

Comment: Where are you planning to write this? It is perfectly fine for colloquial speech but it would not be correct stylistically for anything formal. (I wouldn't use it in school work, for example.)

Comment: It's [despicable](http://www.minionsmovie.com/despicableme.html).

Comment: (Certainly statements like "Stupid me, I forgot to flimflam the ratchet" are quite common.  And if you substitute "Smart me" you're simply employing a bit more sarcasm.)

Answer (score 0):

> Smart me made the same mistake again.

That is correct. By talking about 'smart me'  you are effectively *naming* a entity separate from the self that is speaking.  You are naming a person called 'Smart Me'.

You can also say, "my smart self".

Stylistically or perhaps semantically it seems odd to say that 'intelligent you' failed. That does not hold out much hope for 'stupid you'!

Comment: it seems like sarcasm to me...? But I would add that while this is perfectly fine for colloquial speech, the word *write* makes me wonder about the register.

Comment: @NadjaCS, I think you are right. However, if it is irony then it doesn't work in English in my opinion.

Comment: I think the dissonance is coming from *intelligent* which is not as often used informally. It's the exact same meaning as *smart me*, which you accepted, but it feels wrong because *intelligent me* uses an informal tone and a slightly more formal word. Obviously not totally formal, but enough to make it feel a bit off.

Comment: I think it's more than that. By saying 'smart me', you are not attributing smartness to yourself but to a hypothetical 'other' you--the smarter part of you. Because of that it isn't so much irony as a straight contradiction. Maybe it would work better with for example, "I'm so clever I couldn't even solve the riddle."

Comment: I'm pretty sure "smart me made the same mistake again" is irony or sarcasm, not some kind of disassociation with the mistake. Imagine it said with an eye-roll. I don't think the speaker believes that their smarter portion is making mistakes.

Comment: HotLicks has given the normal usage,  "*Stupid me, I forgot to flimflam the ratchet*"  Changing it to "*Smart me...*" just sounds wrong to my ear.   I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I don't know what the infernal idiot was thinking, whoever they might be, voting down your answer. People are mad with power around here. Your answer is, in fact, perfect. I'm upvoting it to compensate.

Comment: Agree about the mad with power. This is a weird SE site, IMO.

Comment: @NadjaCS - You ain't seen nothing yet, I assure you. Wait till ... well ... I don't want to spoil it for you.

Comment: btw I wasn't disagreeing with this answer (downvote wasn't me), merely commenting that a) it wouldn't be an appropriate mode of speech in all situations and b) I don't see a significant difference between *smart me* and *intelligent me* except that one is slightly more formal. I see it as essentially the same as the example with *I'm so clever*; self-deprecating humor or perhaps it's Eeyore speaking. I dunno.